# App Inventor 2 labels not showing

Tags: android, app-inventor

OK, so here's the thing. I am new to App Inventor and have only been using it for 3 weeks now for a project at school. So using App Inventor it has been one hell of a ride with the block-based programming instead of usual text-based programming (or basically actual programming) and now I have ran into an issue.

I have searched the code and attributes of the elements myself and found nothing and I am wondering if its a corruption error or something but either way I need help. The label isn't showing. It is apparent in the designer but on the emulator it isn't. I tried making another label and it turned out not to show as well, however, I noticed that on the emulator there was space where the two labels should be (the space got bigger when I added the second label) so I'd assume that is good indication that the labels are there or something.

Here is pictures of the designer, code and emulator:

[image: App Inventor designer]
[image: App Inventor code blocks]
[image: App Inventor emulator]

Help would greatly be appreciated!

- Alex :3

Answer (score 0):

Just set the label visible to true. Maybe you forgot about it. Go to the label properties. Then, make sure the visible box is checked.